# relationship array null when eager loading in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am having issues getting the relationship array back when eager loading in laravel 4. for example:

controller:

```
         foreach (Apps::with('extra')->get() as $app)
         {
                 print_r($app->toArray());//returns array but my relationship array at the bottom  says null
                echo $app->extra; //this will show my relationship details

        }
```

model:

```
class Apps extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql_2';
    protected $table = 'apps';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'name';


     public function host()
     {
           return $this->belongsTo('Hosts','name');
     }

     public function extra()
     {
            $this->primaryKey='app_ip';
           return $this->hasone('Extra','ip');
     }

  //other functions below.......

}

class Extra extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql_3';
    protected $table = 'extra';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'ip';

    public function app(){
            return $this->belongsTo('Apps', 'app_ip');
}
```

mysql:

My mysql tables were not created through laravel they were previously existent. the app_ip column in the Apps table relates to the ip column in the extra table. it is a 1 to 1 relationship and I have specified the primary key in the relationship function. I am getting relationships back so I know that it is working.

I am able to get relationship data back when I call the function directly, but it does not show the relationship data when I try and print the full array. The main goal is to be able to return both the relationship columns and the app columns in one response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
$apps = Apps::all();
$apps->load('extra');
foreach ($apps as $app)
{
   print_r($app->toArray()); // prints your relationship data as well
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your model class (Apps and Extra) and SQL table structure?

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work and iterating through the collection or using ->load() to eager load shouldn't make a difference. Are you using the visible restriction on your models? If so you will need to include the relationships.

```
class Apps extends Eloquent {

    protected $visible = array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'created_at',
        'extra', // Make the relationship 'visible'
    );

    public function extra()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Extra');
    }

}
```

Comment: Collin, actually it does make a difference if you are trying to get the related models into the toArray() method. Laravel's eager loading does not assume toArray() needs to load the related models. Therefore you need to explicitly do that by calling the load() method. Check here: http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent under heading Lazy Eager Loading.

Comment: Glad, Look at the source for load() and with(). Both use the same underlying method for loading relations.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L522

Comment: Yes, and this is why what the asker has written will not work without additionally loading the related models. I have tried this with actual code.

Comment: Glad, maybe he changed his example after you initially read it but he is using with() "foreach (Apps::with('extra')->get() as $app)"